# Oracle to Sql server Migration is very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, ssis

SSIS package Details

```
SOURCE- ORACLE database       
Connection Manager:- Native oledb\Microsoft OLE DB Provider For Oracle   

Destination SQL SERVER database     
Connection Manager:-Native oledb\SQL SERVER Native Client 10.0
```

Currently, the Data migration is very slow, Kindly let me know any suggestions to speedup the migration.

Comment: How can you say that migration is slow? Post some evidences.

Comment: It's just migrating 1000 records in 10 mins.

Comment: You need to tell us a lot more than this before we can provide you with any kind of real performance help.  You should be telling us how the SSIS package is written, describing its contents, connection managers and transforms.  You should be letting us know what the CPU and network utilizations are on the source, target and execution boxes.  And you should be telling us how you can tall how fast it is going.  And that's a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

This can be down to many things, and you will just have to check loads of stuff.

- Network Speed (more below)
- Load on Oracle server - CPU, Disk, Network
- Load on SQL Server - CPU, Disk, Network

I did a large Oracle to SQLServer migration a few years ago, using SSIS. When I ran the SSIS packages on my desktop machine, the data path was from my desktop to the Oracle Server in the Data Centre over a fast WAN, data back to my desktop, data out to the SQL Server in a different Data Centre. The speed was not good.

We ended up running the SSIS packages on the the SQL Server machine.This was far, far faster - by about an order of between 10 and 100 as I remember. Making the network path be DC <-> DC instead of DC <-> Desktop -> DC was the difference.

Cheers -

Answer (score 0):

Lots of potential bottlenecks here. Hard to know with so few details provided in the question. Can you post more details and maybe a screenshot of your SSIS package data flow? In general, these can help you rule out a few things:

1. Rule out SQL Server destination as an issue

   - Remove the SQL Server destination from your data flow
   - Add a Union All transformation
   - Connect your Oracle source to the Union All
   - Do not connect the Union All transformation to a destination
   - Execute your data flow
   - If its slow, you know that you have an issue with your Oracle source
   - If its fast, you know you have an issue with your SQL Server destination
2. Are there indexes on your SQL Server destination table?

   - Consider removing them prior to the insert and rebuilding them after
3. OLE DB Destination Editor setting (these are probably your defaults)

   - Data access mode: Table or view - fast load
   - Table lock (check)
   - Maximum insert commit size: 2147483647